# Not able to inflate Google Maps API v2 in fragment twice

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

Ok, I have already checked out about 100 SO QA.

Here is the story: I have a SlidingMenu which has lets say "Create Event" and "All Events" items. "Create Event" menu has a Maps Fragment which is as below. User selects "Create Event" and maps is on screen with no error, than user selects "All Events" and events are shown and user selects "Create Events" again and boom:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #45: Duplicate id 0x7f040058, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for pl.mg6.android.maps.extensions.SupportMapFragment
```

CreateEventFragment is created everytime when user selects from left menu:

```
public void showCreateNewEventFragment() {
    CreateEventFragment fragment = new CreateEventFragment();
    showFragment(fragment);
    slidingMenu.showContent();
}
```

create_event.xml

```
...    
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/searchLayout"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@color/app_color"
    android:padding="6dp" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="pl.mg6.android.maps.extensions.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
...
```

CreateEventFragment.java

```
public class CreateEventFragment extends BaseFragment {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setRetainInstance(true);
    View v = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.create_event, container,
            false);
    ((MainActivity) getActivity())
            .showSlidingMenu(LeftNavigation.ITEM_CREATE_NEW_EVENT);
    initGoogleMaps(v, savedInstanceState);
    return v;
}

private void initGoogleMaps(View v, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    EventshipApplication app = (EventshipApplication) getActivity()
            .getApplication();
        SupportMapFragment mMapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity()
                .getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
        mMap = mMapFragment.getExtendedMap();
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
}
}
```

So, I want to be able to create / use MapFragment more than twice. Is there any suggestions / workarounds?

EDIT:

```
public void showFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for the two maps to behave the exact same way? If I scroll in one map should the other map scroll as well?

Comment: @gian1200 why would you say that, it is perfectly fine to do that

Comment: First, either use nested fragments properly ([using `getChildFragmentManager()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager%28%29)) or do not use nested fragments (e.g., subclass `SupportMapFragment` rather than wrap it). Second, **never call lifecycle methods yourself**, such as the `onCreate()` and `onResume()` calls that you are making in `initGoogleMaps()`. If neither of those help, the problem probably lies in `showFragment()`. Post the implementation of this method and the complete stack trace.

Comment: Thank you. I called lifecycle methods to test another answer, you are right. I edit my question and added showFragment method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
v = app.getMapLayout();
    if (v == null) {
        v = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.create_event, container, false);
        app.setMapLayout(v);
    } else {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();
        parent.removeView(v);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `replace()` instead of `add()`, as you already have a fragment in `android.R.id.content` the second time that you call `showFragment()`.

You may also need to pop the previous transaction off the back stack, or get rid of the `addToBackStack()` call.

Comment: Thanks but not working. Now maps is not showing at second call of fragment : `if (createNewEventFragment == null)
   createNewEventFragment = new CreateEventFragment();
  FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, createNewEventFragment);
  transaction.commit();
  slidingMenu.showContent();`

Comment: @CommonsWare , i am already using `replace` function but still m getting duplicate id error